# Unable to parse string "5573 1189 4017 1207 4768 8542 17 1189 5085 5773" at position 0

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q15qZ.png)I am working on building a model on movie review datsets, i have recieved data set in the form of numbers as object type, I have tried astype and pd.to_numeric to convert from string to int but failed to do so.
Kindly help me with this.

Thanks in Advance,
Karim

Comment: Your string is not one int, what are you tried to do ?

Comment: I am trying to predict 0 s and 1 s from these....for that have to convert to int from object.

Answer (score 1):

@azro is correct. In order to convert a string to int via int() you have to make the string one int by getting rid of the white spaces with either many ints: string.split(" "), or one int: string.replace(" ", "")

Comment: Will try that and get back to you

Comment: this even throws error@sebastian